# (Typescript) Can't log a number to string

Tags: typescript

[screenshots of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UMf0.jpg)

I have a player who has health, and I set it initially to 100.  Then I have made a static function to get the player's health, so I can use this in my health bar class.

In the health bar class use the static function to get the players health, for now I want to log in into the console. But I am still getting undefined in the console.

I already tried this: `console.log("" + check);` and `console.log(String(check));` and `console.log(check.toString());` but I still got undefined in the console.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to it. Images are not good source for code as you can't copy/paste from them and the images might not be available in the future.

Comment: You code may not work because the order you execute the things. You should either post all your code (in text, not screenshots) or a minimal, not working, example.

Comment: improved grammar and sentence structure

Comment: spelling and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your player AFTER trying to read its health.

Check your console logs. It says:

```
undefined
Player has been created.
```

Comment: Thx! It worked. I feel so stupid right now.. I'm new to this hehe.